# Matching pattern that is part of a previous match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to construct an expression that matches incorrectly-placed li tags. For the most part, it is working well except for the fact that one of the occurrences that I need to match are part of a previous match.

Here's my expression:

```
/(<li>.*?)(<\/li>)(.*?)(<br><(li|\/ul)>)/gi
```

The text I am attempting to match is as follows:

```
<ul><br><li> text before invalid closing tag</li> remaining text<br><li> this should also be matched</li> but isn't<br><li> text before invalid closing tag</li> remaining text<br></ul><br>
```

There should be 3 matches here, but I am only getting 2 of them. You can test this on the link below, but the middle section is not being matched. I'm not sure of the correct way to get it to match text that is of a previous match.

http://regexr.com/3cp2v

Comment: can you give more information on how we can say that an `li` tag is `incorrectly-placed`

Comment: It's incorrect in the context in which this data is used in an application, but not necessarily from this markup perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to come to a solution by matching the pattern up to either the next opening *li* or closing *ul* tag. This prevented my matches from overlapping and got my results grouped as desired.

```
/(<li>.*?)(<\/li>)(.*?)<br>(?=<(li|\/ul)>)/gi
```